# Optimization - Finding the set of all feasible directions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

**The problem at hand is the following:** Consider the set $S =\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2} : y^2\le x\le y \}$. Draw the set $S$ and the set of all feasible directions at $(1,1)$.

I tried to use the definition of feasible directions (for a given point $a\in S$ we call a direction $d\neq 0$ feasible if $a+td\in S$ for $0\le t\le \delta $ if $\delta\gt 0$ is small enough).

I also tried to use the fact that $d^T\nabla g(1,1)\le 0$.

Could you please help me figure out how they got to the following answer: The set of all feasible directions at $(1,1)$ is $S =\{(x,y)\in R^2 : x\le y\lt x/2 \}$

Comment: The set $S$ is already given, there is no need to redefine it.  It looks like $x \leq y < x/2$ is a typo (and certainly does not contain $(1,1)$).  The original set $S = \{(x,y): y^2 \leq x \leq y\}$ has a flat bottom and a curvy top and looks like a football chopped in half. The point $(1,1)$ is the tip of the football.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear enough. However the set $S =\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2} : x\le y\lt x/2 \}$ is the set of all feasible directions. And I'm not sure how they concluded to that answer.

Comment: Then lets call it something other than $S$, say, $F = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x \leq y  < x/2\}$ (notice that this set requires both $x$ and $y$ to be negative).  If you look at the tip of the football (i.e., point $(1,1)$), you can see the feasible directions are bounded by a top curve (with slope 1/2 at $(1,1)$) and a bottom line of slope 1.  So extreme directions in which we can move are bounded by $d_1 = (-1,-1)$ (achievable since it moves down the bottom line) and $d_2=(-1, -1/2)$ (not achievable since it is tangent to the top curve) and this corresponds to the set $F$.